# Colorbox fluid layout only on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, resize, width, colorbox, fluid

I need to have colorbox window with static width (it is actualy dynamic - depends on css specified width or image actual width etc...) except mobile version. I'm doing responsive website. When I resize browser window it always have fixed width, but when I'm on mobile the colorbox window is wider than broser window - it doesn't resize to fit the browser window screen. I apply this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $.colorbox.resize({width: '100%'});
});
```

This help, but if I return to non mobile device or when I resize browser window it stays at 100%. But at this point I want to return colorbox window to have static width as previous. Keep in mind that previous width is based on content width (image width) or css specified width.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you only want the colorbox to be 100% width when user resize the window? Notice what you did in your JS is not detecting whether user is on a mobile device.

It seems like you should use media queries instead. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries